# single table inheritance with embeds_one mogoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, single-table-inheritance, ruby-1.9.2

I have a model

```
class Post
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  embeds_one :comment
end
```

and I have comment class

```
class Comment
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  embedded_in :post

  field :title
  field :description
end
```

And I have another class inherited from comment

```
class RecentComment < Comment
  # certain methods
end
```

Now I want to be able to create `RecentComment` through `post` if I do `Post.last.build_comment(:_type => "RecentComment")` the new comment will not be of `_type:"RecentComment"`, and similarly if I do `Post.last.build_recent_comment`, it gives me error saying sth like `undefined method build_recent_comment for Post class`. If the `post` had `references_many :comments` I should have done `Post.last.build_comments({}, RecentComment)` without any problems. But I don't know about how to build an object with `RecentComment` class in this case. If anybody could help that'd be gr8!

Note: I am using `gem 'mongoid', '~> 2.0.1'`

Comment: You probably just need to put each comment type explicitly into the Post class- embeds_one :old_comment; embeds_one :new_comment ...

Comment: I guess that's one of the problems with creating subclasses of Comment. Is there any benefit of having the subclasses? You can have a lot of classes that are all the same except the names. If it's possible you might want to refactor now before it becomes harder. Otherwise I'm not sure how to create the associations that you want without explicitly making each one an embedded doc.

Comment: but all the derived classes have same fields and properties as comment so will it be appropriate to make all of them different embedded doc?

Comment: it is already late.. i have all my controllers and methods using that association. maybe i asked the question too late. Anyways thanks for trying to help!

Comment: What is the difference between a RecentComment and regular Comment?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe try

```
class Post
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  embeds_one :recent_comment, :class_name => Comment
```

and just make your Comment class polymorphic

```
class Comment
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :type
  validates_inclusion_of :type, :in => ["recent", "other"]
```

Comment: actually there are other derived classes in comments like recentcomment, oldcomment and newcomment. If there was only one derived class i am sure your answer would have been ideal.

Answer (score 1):

one option is to try something like:

```
class RecentComment < Comment
  store_in "comment"

  #set the type you want
end
```

but you might just use timestamps
and scope to retrieve your recent, 
old comment, new_comment and such,

like within the comment class

```
scope :recent, where("created_at > (Time.now - 1.day)")
```

then you can do:

```
post.comments.recent
```